# How to change JS form to return 'John Doe' in Chrome/Firefox/Edge and not 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, undefined

I have an old JavaScript form that gets user-data from a mySQL-database.
It displays the new customers email, street address and name correct in IE11 but in Chrome/Firefox/Edge the name is shown as 'undefined'.

I checked the PHP code which does a browser check:

...

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
function checkBrowser(){ //Browsercheck (needed)
    this.ver=navigator.appVersion
    this.agent=navigator.userAgent
    this.dom=document.getElementById?1:0
    this.opera5=this.agent.indexOf('Opera 5')>-1
    this.ie4=(document.all && !this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0;
    this.ie5=(this.ver.indexOf('MSIE 5')>-1 && this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0; 
    this.ie6=(this.ver.indexOf('MSIE 6')>-1 && this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0;
    this.ie7=(this.ver.indexOf('MSIE 7')>-1 && this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0;
    this.ie8=(this.ver.indexOf('MSIE 8')>-1 && this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0;
    this.ie9=(this.ver.indexOf('MSIE 9')>-1 && this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0;
    this.other=(this.ver.indexOf('U')>-1 && this.dom && !this.opera5)?1:0;
    this.ie=this.ie4||this.ie5||this.ie6||this.ie7||this.ie8||this.ie9||this.other
    this.mac=this.agent.indexOf('Mac')>-1
    this.ns6=(this.dom && parseInt(this.ver) >= 5) ?1:0; 
    this.ns4=(document.layers && !this.dom)?1:0;
    this.bw=(this.other || this.ie9 || this.ie8 || this.ie7 || this.ie6 || this.ie5 || this.ie4 || this.ns4 || this.ns6 || this.opera5 || this.opera6 || this.opera7 || this.opera8 || this.opera9)
    return this
}
bw=new checkBrowser();
```

a bit further down I have those lines:

...

```
if(bw.ns4)
document.divMessage.document.input_form.name.value = name[current_id];
```

...

```
else
document.input_form.name.value = name[current_id];
```

...

No idea where to start to fix this problem.

I wonder if it could be a problem with the Chrome Rendering-Engine and not the browser version because IE is not using it, right?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include a [mre]